# how do I combine fields and verbiage

Tags: sql-server-2008

I would to combine table values in a few places within the out put of a select statement

```
Select some verbiage, field1, some more verbiage, field4, more verbiage, field5
From table1
Where Field1 = xxx
```

Can someone show me the proper syntax?

Thanks

Comment: Please show some data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Just combine the literals (constant values, or "verbiage" as you refer to them), and place single quotes around the literals:

```
SELECT 
  'Some text', Field1, 'More text', Field4, 'Yet More Text', Field5
FROM 
  Table1
WHERE 
  Field1 = xxx
```

Your comment asks about a sentence rather than separate columns. This should work:

```
SELECT 
  'Some text' + Field1 + 'More text' + Field4 + 'Yet More Text' + Field5
```

If any of the columns (fields) are not of a character (string) type, you'll need to use `CAST` to convert them into a character type in order to concatenate them with `+`. I can't help you with that, because you failed to provide any information about your columns in your question.

Comment: lol  thanks...can i make that entire output one paragraph as opposed to columns?

Comment: Next time, put that request in your question in the first place, and I'd have given it to you to start. :) It helps if you make your questions clear as far as what you're asking.